# Infinite loop in my summing code

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I can't figure out why there is an infinite loop in my code.
Once I enter my input array, something wrong happens and the console doesn't stop taking input. Can someone help?
Here is the code which might have a problem :

```
public static triplet<Integer,Integer,Integer> maxsum(int[] input)
{
    triplet<Integer,Integer,Integer> ans=new triplet<Integer, Integer, Integer>(0,0,0);

    int l=input.length;
    int maxSum=0;
    int i=0;

    while(i<input.length);
    {
        System.out.println("input taken");
        int j=i;
        int sum=0;
        if(input[i]>=0)
        {
            while(j>=0&&j<l)
            {
                sum=sum+input[j];
            }
            if(sum>maxSum)
            {
                ans.c=sum;
                ans.b=j;
                ans.a=i;
            }
            i=j+1;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping your inner loop.

Perhaps you should change

```
while(j >= 0 && j < l)
{
    sum = sum + input[j];
}
```

to

```
while(input[j] >= 0 && j < l)
{
    sum = sum + input[j];
    j++;
}
```

and

```
        if(sum>maxSum)
        {
            ans.c=sum;
            ans.b=j;
            ans.a=i;
        }
```

to

```
        if(sum>maxSum)
        {
            ans.c=sum;
            ans.b=j;
            ans.a=i;
            maxSum=sum;
        }
```

Comment: i want to update i to j+1 if the sum > maxsum and if its not then i want to update it to i++;

Comment: @newMe What do you want the inner loop to do?

Comment: i actually want to find a subarray with max sum. so I take i as the beginning index of subarray and j as the last index of subarray. and with i=i+j, i want to access the next subarray where i is again its beginning index

Comment: @newMe Then perhaps the inner loop condition should be `while(input[j] >= 0 && j < l)`. Though I don't think this will find the sub-array with largest sum, since the largest sum may contain negative elements.

Comment: i changed it. still infinte loop :/
but wont the condition input[j]>=0 eliminate any negative element ?
i am new to programming. sorry for the messy code though

Comment: @newMe If you added j++ to the inner loop, you shouldn't have an infinite loop anymore. Yes, `input[j]>=0` will eliminate negative elements, which means this code will find the sub-set of non-negative elements having the highest sum, which is not necessarily the same as the sub-set of elements having the highest sum. BTW, you should also modify `maxSum` if you want your code to work.

Comment: i want to find maxsum for only positive entries. i changed maxSum value too. and added j++ too. still some problem. but thanks a lot !!!!